# Spring Security permitAll doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security. I have a Controller in which some methods have to be possible to access by any user regardless if he is authenticated or not, some methods have to be possible to access only to users who are authenticated with a JWT token. I have configured some paterns with acces="permitAll()" but it seems not to work. If I try to access localhost:8080/name-of-the-app/services/public/whatever I get 401 which I return in my MobileJWTAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence method. Can you help me?

This is my context.xml:

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

<security:http entry-point-ref="mobileJWTAuthenticationEntryPoint"
               authentication-manager-ref="mobileJWTAuthenticationManager"
               create-session="stateless"
               use-expressions="true">
    <security:custom-filter ref="mobileJWTAuthenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/public/**" access="permitAll()"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/restAPI/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>

<bean id="mobileJWTAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="co.amleto.server.services.security.MobileJWTAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

<bean id="mobileJWTAuthenticationFilter" class="co.amleto.server.services.security.MobileJWTAuthenticationFilter" >
    <constructor-arg name="authenticationManager" ref="mobileJWTAuthenticationManager"/>
    <constructor-arg name="entryPoint" ref="mobileJWTAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mobileJWTAuthenticationProvider" class="co.amleto.server.services.security.MobileJWTAuthenticationProvider"/>

<security:authentication-manager alias="mobileJWTAuthenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="mobileJWTAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

EDIT: My whole code is inspired by this: http://massimilianosciacco.com/spring-security-jwt-authentication. In the AuthenticationFilter I've switched throws with returns. Now I get blank page regardless which url I hit.

Comment: what's the version of the spring-security ?

Comment: Spring: 4.2.2.RELEASE
Spring Security: 4.0.3.RELEASE

Comment: I think that you are using a configuration of an old version of Spring Security. try to use `access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"`and for the authenticated users put the ROLE_USER. try to read more the user guide

Comment: But which element of my config indicates that it is old?

Comment: this section will explain to you the differance between the version 3.2.x and 4.x: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-filter-security-metadata-source.

Comment: Still I don't see anything deprecated in my config. I switched to IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY and added use-expressions="false", but there is no change in the behaviour of my app.

Comment: Try permitAll instead of permitAll().

Comment: Nope. No difference. Please see my updated OP. I've added a link to the article on which I based my code. Maybe the implementation of the provider is wrong.

Comment: Actually there is one thing: I've replaced throws from the original code with returns in my provider. Now I get blank page whatever url I hit.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. As I've mentioned in the edit, my code is based on the solution from the link added in the OP. Custom filter had wrong code: in every situation exceptions were thrown. The solution was to invoke chain.doFilter(request, response) and return from the doFilter method to allow anonymous url invocation.